# Are focusing adverbs exceptions of adverb definitions?

Tags: adverbs, focusing-adverbs

> “Adverbs characteristically modify verbs and other categories except nouns, especially adjectives and adverbs.” (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p.563)
>
> “The basic division, then, is between words that modify nouns, and words that modify other categories (categories of words or of larger constituents). The noun modifiers are adjectives, and the others are adverbs.”
> (A Student’s Introduction to English Grammar by Huddleston & Pullum, p.123)

Even though adverbs are excluded, by said definition, from modifying nouns, the so-called focusing adverbs are found in CGEL and COCA, that modify nouns, proper nouns and pronouns.

> You are the **only** boy. 
> **Only** Kim resigned. 
> **Only** he knows.

Can they be regarded as exceptions of the definition? Or is there a certain reason, for example, the focusing range being movable or sometimes ambiguous we cannot say definitely that the adverbs modify only nouns?

Comment: In _You are the only boy_, I'd say _only_ is simply an adjective. That does not answer for the other two examples, though...

Comment: "Focussing adverb" is not a standard term. And definitions of "adverb" are usually useless for identification. _Only_ is a Quantifier. Like all quantifiers, it has lots of special syntax. And it has a very complex meaning; part assertion, part presupposition. Larry Horn explains them in [his classic 1969 paper](http://ling.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/horn/Horn1969_CLS5.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Then, would it be better to use 'focusing modifier' than 'focusing adverb'. When it modifies noun or NP, it's like adjective; modifies the others, adverbial.

Comment: No problem, if you have a usable definition of "focussing". Also of "modification", since quantifiers don't always "modify" the same word that they "focus on" or "bind". Inventing new grammatical terminology is a good way to make sure nobody else will ever understand you -- or anyone you've taught with it.

Comment: I've long considered that even when say 'only' attaches [not a 'standard grammatical usage' of 'attaches'] to the verb {He only asked}, it is not really modifying the verb in any meaningful sense, but is saying something beyond the content of the statement {He asked}: 'The only thing he did was to ask'. This is not a basic adverbial function. It's time these usages were better analysed and separated, in the same way that determiners are now distinguished from adjectives.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ve read your words [here](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23884). Bas Aarts says relative clause is an adjunct which modifies antecedents. But in CGEL or your words, it’s hard to say that ‘adjunct’ includes the words modifying nouns. In ‘He died young (CGEL,p.263)’, is ‘young’ a modifier of ‘he’, ‘died’, or ‘he died’?

Comment: In the expanded forms 'He was young when he died' / 'He died when he was young' it is inconceivable that 'young' should be analysed as anything other than an adjective. But the when-clause has an obvious adverbial function (cf 'He died yesterday'). The problem is that the common and grammatically acceptable elided form uses the _adjective_ ? _ex-adjective_ ? to stand in for the whole adverbial clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Then can we say ‘young’ itself is adjective categorically, yet its function is adverbial adjunct and simultaneously depicts/predicates the subject? As the writers differentiate determinatives and determiners.

Comment: I'm getting to understand more and more why John Lawler advises against setting too much store by having a slavish devotion to analyses based on 'word class'. But you're probably not wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is in this passage:

> [Adjectives are] words that modify nouns, and [adverbs are] words that modify other categories (categories of words or of larger constituents).

Here, *only* is modifying a "larger constituent"—namely, a [noun phrase (NP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/noun_phrase). You have given examples where the noun phrase consists of one word, but if you replace the noun phrase with a multi-word one, you would see that *only* would have to apply to the entire phrase, and not just with a single noun.

Consider if we replaced the noun with a longer noun phrase:

> Only [Kim] resigned → Only [Sarah and Kim] resigned.

Note that *only* modifies the whole phrase, and not just the noun itself.

Comment: Yes, but I could probably convince myself that *"Sarah and only one other director resigned"* might be valid in some contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sure--where *only* is modifying the constituent "one other director"

Comment: @FumbleFingers but you're right--my example is misleading because single-word constituents can still be modified. I have removed that part of my answer.

Comment: I'm far from convinced the *adverb/adjective* distinction is as important as the constant stream of related questions here might suggest (Don't you linguistics johnnies sometimes just use *adverb* for both anyway?). But contrasting *"I smoke **only** cigars and cigarettes"* with *"I smoke **small** cigars and cigarettes"*, it seems clear to me that the scope of "only" more readily stretches across the entire noun phrase. Or is that just a fluke of the pragmatics/semantics of the particular nouns?

Comment: Us linguistic johnnies use it to describe characteristic **usage**, not characteristic lexical items. Adverbs are constituents that are characteristically oblique in semantics and variable in positioning options. They should be thought of as peripheral to the sentence -- afterthoughts, qualifications, etc. I prefer to use a non-structural metaphor, since adverbs are pretty floppy things to use in construction. The proposition is the nourishment, and adverbs are garnish, flavoring, or hot sauce; like a sauce, the exact modificational range of an adverb is a bit problematic.

Comment: The whole concept of 'modification' is rarely explained. In 'a possible future president', it stretches the concept of modification enormously to be able to say that the 'adjectives' are modifying the noun.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to address *You are **the** only boy* where it would be hard to argue that only is modifying an NP because it occurs after the nominal.

Answer (score 0):

> You are the only boy.
>
> Only Kim resigned.
>
> Only he knows.

No, they are not exceptions.

In your first sentence, *only* is an Adjective. And occurs in a Noun Phrase structure - Determinative + [adjective + Head Noun]<sub>NOMINAL</sub>

In your second and third sentence *only* is a *Focusing Modifier*<sub>FUNCTION</sub> and here it's not an Adjective, it's an Adverb.

In your second sentence, *only* modifies the whole clause - *Kim resigned*. And similarly in your third sentence, it modifies *he knows*.

CaGEL says Focusing Modifiers can have multiple focusing elements, and depending on that the meaning can vary. The syntactically modified constituents can sometime contain the focused element, or it may contain not.

It should be further noted that CaGEL does say that Personal Pronouns can take such Focusing Modifiers (realized by Adverbs) as External Modifiers.

> It's done by him only.