# Can 'even' modify a noun?

Tags: nouns, adverbs

It has been said that an adverb cannot modify a noun.

But [this article](https://www.thestreet.com/story/14545816/1/why-tech-heavy-weights-may-show-interest-in-tivo.html)'s title is:

> Google, Amazon or Even Apple Could Buy Tivo

Here, 'even' I think is an adverb but it does seem to modify the following noun 'Apple'.

How is this possible? Is this an exception to the rule that an adverb cannot modify a noun?

Comment: [Adverbs modifying nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/303767/44619) also related [Are focusing adverbs exceptions of adverb definitions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/are-focusing-adverbs-exceptions-of-adverb-definitions)

Comment: That's a shame about the DV, maybe if you quote some literature that even cannot modify nouns, or illustrate how "even" modifies *Apple* then maybe the question could be better appreciated.

Comment: Adverbs can occasionally postmodify nouns (e.g. "A **shortage** of timber **internationally** led to a rise in prices" / "Industrial action led to the **withdrawal indefinitely** of the ferry services"). And adverbs like "even" can freely modify NPs: _Even John liked it_ / _We can do it anytime, even tonight_.

Comment: Other examples of an adverb modifying an NP include "I bought almost the last copy" / "Ed is virtually his only friend".

Comment: _Even_ is an intensifier that modifies whole clauses or phrases, not single nouns and will always include a verb, if only semantically. The unexpected, unusual, or extreme case signaled by _even_ in _Even John liked it_ is not "John," but John's liking something. _Even_ shares certain but not all characteristics with _only_ or _also_ and deserves its own answer. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It's a question about the word 'even' specifically, whether it is always an adverb, or is sometimes an adverb sometimes an adjective, or some other analysis.

Comment: "Even" is not an intensifier; it's a 'additive focusing modifier'. In, for example, "Even you would have enjoyed dancing tonight", "tonight" is an NP consisting of just a noun. Many people simply say it is modifying a noun, but in fact it is modifying "tonight", the head of the NP which happens to be a noun. Complicated stuff, what?

Comment: Ah, the Q might live to see another day. I have cast my vote to reopen. And I'm deleting my comments about abbreviations, too!