# "Even the dog refused to eat it" - As even is an adverb here, what exactly is it modifying?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence, adverbs

Silly question but trying to improve my grammar.

> Even the dog refused to eat it.

I am not sure how to express what "even" is modifying. I know that the context is equivalent to *surprisingly* but even cannot modify "The dog" as that is a noun.

Comment: The dog even refused to eat.

Comment: This might answer your question: [Are focusing adverbs exceptions of adverb definitions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188079/are-focusing-adverbs-exceptions-of-adverb-definitions)

Comment: It is modifying the rest of the sentence. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/even

Comment: It is a focus particle, here marking as surprising the fact that _the dog_ is in the set of those refusing to 'eat it'. I'd not use the term 'modifying' so much as 'focusing' on the NP  _the dog_. // 'A focus particle is a particle that accompanies an element that is focused and that expresses various meanings related to the focusing. ... _scalar focus particle_ (e.g. even)' [adding a comment that the inclusion of the item focused on in the set is surprising] [{König, Ekkehard. 1991_Glottopedia](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Focus_particle) The meaning of focus particles. ] >>

Answer (score 2):

While adverbs do not modify nouns, they do modify noun phrases:

> **Probably** the best basketball player of all time, Michael Jordan surely
>   has earned his place in the baseketball hall of fame.

When adverbs are modifying noun phrases, it's not possible to put a commma beteween the the noun phrase and the adverb preceding it:

> *Almost, the whole movie was boring.
>
> Almost the whole movie was boring.

In the example given, *even* seems to be modifying the noun phrase *the dog* as inserting a comma makes it ungrammatical:

> *Even, the dog refused to eat it.
>
> Surprisingly, the dog refused to eat it.

*Surprisingly*, on the other hand, would be an adjunct modifying the whole clause, and hence we could insert a comma.

Comment: It's possible, as your own examples show.  It's just wrong.